# Why's this shutdown one-liner command not working

Tags: command-line, python, shutdown

It works fine from terminal, but when called from a thread in python, it fails.

```
history -d $((HISTCMD-1)) && echo 'password' | sudo -S shutdown -h 08:00
```

from python, here's what I did:

```
halt = "history -d $((HISTCMD-1)) && echo 'password' | sudo -S shutdown -h 08:00"
thread.start_new_thread(lambda: commands.getoutput(halt),())
```

I used lambda after trying it for other commands like opening nautilus or gedit, which works fine, but shutdown command isn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
history -d $((HISTCMD-1)) && echo 'password' | sudo -S shutdown -h 08:00
```

is not actually a command, it's a fragment of shell script. So you need to have the shell execute it. Something like this:

```
import os
halt = "history -d $((HISTCMD-1)) && echo 'password' | sudo -S shutdown -h 08:00"
os.system(halt)
```

Answer (score -1):

From *man sudo*:

> The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the
>   standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be
>   followed by a newline character.

So, after the -S, it's waiting for a NEWLINE character which you provided when using the terminal.

Comment: As the OP said, that command works fine from terminal and indeed, `echo` without `-n` argument will output the trailing newline.